# Writing a pseudo-MIPS assembler and fwrite for binary encoding

Tags: assembly, mips

I am writing a high-level MIPS assembler. I'm having trouble off the bat trying to get fwrite to output correctly. An example assembly file looks like this:

```
.text
    addi    $t0,$0,7 
    addi    $t1,$0,1 
L1: 
    beq $t0,$0,DONE 
    mult    $t1,$t0 
    mflo    $t1  
    addi    $t0,$t0,-1 
    j   L1 
DONE:   
    add $a0,$0,$t1 
    addi    $v0,$0,1 
    syscall 
    addi    $v0,$0,10 
    syscall
```

My code should convert these into 32-bit binary instructions and fwrite them to a file to be read by the faux-CPU.

I have a problem off the bat where the 32-bit delimiter at the beginning of the file should be 0xf0f0f0f0. I know you can't "read" a binary file, but looking at the example file that I have, the delimiter is represented by /360/360/360/360 after being written by fwrite. Why is this and how would I replicate that behavior when I'm writing my own file (as in how do I use fwrite to achieve this to create other binary files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fwrite(3)` for your delimiter would look like this:

```
unsigned int delim = 0xF0F0F0F0;

fwrite(&delim, sizeof delim, 1, output);
```

This writes one object of `delim`'s size to the standard C stream `output`.

You can use `od(1)` or `xxd(1)` to "read" binary files:

```
$ od -bc /etc/passwd
0000000 162 157 157 164 072 170 072 060 072 060 072 162 157 157 164 072
          r   o   o   t   :   x   :   0   :   0   :   r   o   o   t   :
$ xxd /etc/passwd
0000000: 726f 6f74 3a78 3a30 3a30 3a72 6f6f 743a  root:x:0:0:root:
0000010: 2f72 6f6f 743a 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a  /root:/bin/bash.
```

(The `hexer(1)` program (in the `hexer` package on Ubuntu) is a lot like an interactive `xxd(1)`, you might find it useful some day.)

Comment: This is useful but fwrite takes a pointer to an array as the first argument, not an int value

Comment: @flapjackery: then use &delim instead of delim